# Get old Facebook posts from public FB page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For a university research project I need to view some old posts on public Facebook pages from a specific date range (January 22-31 2014.) I was planning just to copy and paste each post but I have run into a problem with some of the pages that generate a very high volume of posts. Facebook will not display past a certain date. Even with scrolling down, at a certain point the posts stop displaying (this is true by month, so it jumps from January 25 directly to December 31 for example).

Here are the pages I am interested in: 
https://www.facebook.com/Syrian.Revolution
https://www.facebook.com/Syrian.Truth

I have read about Facebook's Graph API but have had some trouble using it (I don't have a developer's background.) Also the posts are mostly in Arabic so that may be a problem.

I just need the pages' posts, not the comments sections.

Thanks anyone so much for your help, it is very appreciated.

Comment: Quite a broad ques, but Ill explain you step wise how you can proceed. What language a re you using or comfortable with?

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on what language/environment you're using. As a simplest case, you can just use Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and make a call:

{{page_id}}/posts

There are a lot of ways you can improve this call for your benefit. For example, you can use a limit parameter to increase the default number of results it retruns.

{{page_id}}/posts?limit=200

By default, this returns a lot of fields, you can limit the fields.

{{page_id}}/posts?limit=200&fields=id,message,created_time

You can visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/ to find out which fields are supported.

In order to get results during a certain time-range, you can use the created_time field to determine if a post belongs to a certain time interval.